# How to fix this error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I am new to Javascript. Why is this code giving me the error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`? I have tried to add the datasrc code before but it is not working. Does anyone else have an idea on how to fix it?

```
//implement css in this files
import './style.css';

//jquery already imported
import $ from 'jquery';
// ajax to load

// do table data binding here using data from variable resultArr
var myArray = []

$.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url:'https://www.seetrustudio.com/data.php',
    success:function(response){
        myArray = response.data
        buildTable(myArray)
        console.log(myArray)
    }
})
function buildTable(data){
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var row = `<tr>
                        <td>${data[i].date}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].weather}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].temperature}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].temp_unit}</td>
                  </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row


    }
}`
```

Comment: In your success callback, you have assigned `myArray` to **`response.data`**. Since the `response` has no `data` field, the `myArray` will be `undefined`, and consequently, the `data` passed to the `buildTable` will be undefined too. So if you just use `myArray = response` in your ajax success callback, everything will work correctly. _For your next issues, I suggest you print the result of your variable assignments and API responses, using `console.log`, in order to trace your code and find the origin of the problem easily :)_

Answer (score 0):

There is the only one place in your code where `length` is used: `data.length` in for loop.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
```

So, intepreter tells `I cannot read length of undefined` hence `data` is undefined, hence `myArray` and `response.data` is undefined and you should set a breakpoint on line

```js
myArray = response.data
```

and see what is in the response, and why it's not contains the key `data`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have not updated the API key for my app.
When I have done so, The issue is resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).